# Why doesn't Connect Vertices create an edge as opposed to Make Edge/Face?

Tags: vertices, edges, faces

**Supose we have this scenario:**

[image: Vertices]

Why the ***Connect vertices*** action has no effect but the ***Make Edge/Face*** action does?

Comment: I'd say [Vertex Connect](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html?highlight=connect%20vertex) uses exhisting geometry to cut it through, and this doesn't exhist here.

Comment: @MrZak That is the answer, you should post that. It's basically a lazy, simplified version of the knife tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between them is that **[Connect Vertices](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#connect-vertices)** tool cuts through already exhisting geometry (just like **[Knife Tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?highlight=knife%20tool))**, whereas **[Make Edge/Face](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/creating_faces_and_edges.html?highlight=make%20edge)** creates new one.

In the proposed scenario it's hard to see the difference, so to better demonstrate it I used side of the cube.

#### Connect Vertices

[image]

The tool will cut through exhisting geometry based on selected vertices *which belong to the same face* (so if I selected 3 vertices where one vertice per face, there wouldn't be any effect)

#### Connect Vertex Path

<sub>(I decided to put it also here because for some time I couldn't get the difference)</sub>
[image]

The result of using Connect Vertex Path command (<kbd>J</kbd>). The order of selecting vertices is important; whether vertices belong to the same face is not. The adjacent faces were splitted, becoming tris now.

#### Make Edge/Face

[image]

Make Edge/Face (<kbd>F</kbd>) will simply create new face there atop of exhisting one, not splitting anything.